# ffmpeg set output resolution by resizing image

Tags: video, ffmpeg, resolution, image-resizing

I'm trying to use ffmpeg for rendering video where an audio file and image are taken as inputs, and turned into a video (basically a music video) with the audio file playing for the duration of the video.

My current working command:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i "front.png" -i "testWAVfile.wav" -vf "scale=2*trunc(iw/2):2*trunc(ih/2),setsar=1,format=yuv420p" -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a aac -shortest -vf scale=1920:1080  "outputVideo.mp4"
```

Will set the output resolution of the video to whatever the resolution of the image is. Is there a way I can resize the image to enlarge it by a couple multiplications so that the output video resolution will be higher?

Like if my `front.png` image was 800x800 pixels, I could add something to my ffmpeg command to triple the resolution, so that the output video resolution is 2400x2400?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method is to use `scale=iw*3:-1`.

However, since using libx264 with yuv420p requires width x height to be divisible by 2 use `scale=2*trunc(iw/2*3):-2`.

Or just declare the size you want: `scale=2400:-1`

Example:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i "front.png" -i "testWAVfile.wav" -vf "scale=2*trunc(iw/2*3):-2,setsar=1,format=yuv420p" -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage -crf 18 -c:a aac -shortest "outputVideo.mp4"
```

- See [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) filter and [expression](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation) documentation for more info.
- Note that you should only use one `-vf` at a time as the other will be ignored.
- Upscaling is not recommended if you can avoid it. There quality will not be better as the additional information is simply interpolated.
- Many players won't like a frame rate of 2, so consider increasing it to 6 or more if you need full compatibility. If you're just uploading to YouTube then don't worry about it as it should be able to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Scale the image front.png using the ffmpeg cmd

```
ffmpeg -i front.png -vf scale=2400:2400 output_2400x2400.png
```

use the output of this cmd (output_2400x2400.png as input image) in your working video generating cmd

```
-vf scale=2400:2400
```